# GA traffic not showing, script seems to be ok

Tags: magento2, google-analytics, google-api

I just cant figure out why GA isn't tracking the traffic. Code seems to implemented correctly, but GA is showing close to no traffic.

We are using 2.3.2 and I want to avoid updating, as we are switching away from Magento anyhow. I just want to get some info because the former consultant completely turned of all tracking and it would be nice to have some last info before switching over.

that is the code which is in every page, even a test-access from the GA console does not show visitors. I am using a clean google chrome for viewing. We are in the EU, so maybe some stuff with GDPR is turned on - I can't find anything.

```
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_GoogleAnalytics/js/google-analytics": {
            "isCookieRestrictionModeEnabled": 0,
            "currentWebsite": 1,
            "cookieName": "user_allowed_save_cookie",
            "ordersTrackingData": [],
            "pageTrackingData": {"optPageUrl":"","isAnonymizedIpActive":false,"accountId":"UA-1XXXXXXX-2"}        }
    }
}
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
```

Comment: Hi Chris, does it work before? Could I ask you why you decide to switch away from Magento?

Comment: Yes, it worked before, just not sure what was changed. We decided to switch away from Magento due to Admin issues. We have three systems deployed (stone-age typo3 version, wordpress, magento) and we wanted to harmonize all, so we go to all WP/WooC. It does all we need, plus is easier to handle. We would have needed to invest heavily in our Magento System and that was just the better way forward.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. From the Administration area of Google Analytics > **Ecommecre Settings** >  **Ecommerce set-up**, make sure **Enable Ecommerce** and **Enhanced Ecommerce Reporting** are turned on, and you have the correct Tracking ID which gets from the Administration area of Google Analytics > **Shop** > **Tracking Info** > **Tracking Code**.